# How can I make this perl command check for subfolders as well?

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file

I'm running Windows 10 and I have a batch file that changes the directory to the required location and a perl command that edits all text files in it by changing Enabled = 1 to Enabled = 0, but I can't figure out how to make the perl command check for subfolders.

```
@echo off
timeout 1 >nul 2>&1
cd /d D:
timeout 1 >nul 2>&1
cd "D:\MySettings"
timeout 1 >nul 2>&1
perl -wE "@ARGV = glob qq($ARGV[0]); $^I = qq(); while (<>) { s/Enabled =\K.*/ \x220\x22/g; print }" *.txt
Pause
```

Comment: You are trying to emulate the functionality of `-p -i`, the edit-in-place combo. But why not just use the switches directly? If it's about the globbing, just put that in a `BEGIN` block.

Comment: [`File::Find`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) is a core module that allows you to traverse folders recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To process files in subfolders as well, and (I presume) in sub-sub-folders, etc, that list of all "entries" (`glob`) need be split into files and folders.  Edit the files and repeat the process in subfolders. This is often done recursively but there are other ways. It's a little job to do.

And there are libraries for recursive traversal and processing, of course. For example the core [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) (or [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule)), or [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule).  But since you also need to edit each file in a simple manner let's look at a more general utility [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny), which has a few methods for editing files in-place, as well.

If you insist on a command-line program ("one-liner")

```
perl -MPath::Tiny -we"
    path(qq(.))->visit( sub { 
        my ($entry, $state) = @_; 
        return if not -T;
        path($entry)->edit_lines( sub { s/.../.../g } )
    }, 
    { recurse => 1 }
)"
```

Here the `visit` method executes the `sub { }` callback on each entry under the given folder, and goes on recursively (with that option).  We skip entries which aren't ASCII or UTF-8 files, by `-T` [filetest](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X).

Inside the callback, `edit_lines` processes each line of the file as specified in its `sub`; in this case, run the  regex from the question. Once it's done with the whole file it replaces the original with the edited version.  See docs.

Comment: `-wE` switches should probably be `-e`, or possibly `-we`. Not using any extended features in this code. And warnings are probably going to be spam for a bulk command.

Comment: @TLP Quite correct, thank you. (There's almost always some print so it's easy to forget...).  Warnings I can't do without (the fingers reject) -- they can turn them off if they want.  I'll comment though, good call

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late response. I learned from this response and modified it slightly to fit my needs. it is perfect. thank you so much @zdim!

Comment: @LGZana Great that it helps :)  Let me know if there are questions

Answer (score 1):

For this, I think it could be only done by perl commands, not in batch commands.

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370067/how-do-i-check-for-a-sub-subdirectory-in-perl) for more specific solutions

Comment: This answer should probably be a comment instead.